# Android: dynamically registering my receivers in a non-UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I'm trying to optimise my android app and decided to transfer all my receivers which I register in the `onStart` method to a thread that is started within the `onStart` method instead. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Timber.e( "onStart");
    super.onStart();
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(locationReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(Constants.MAIN_ACTIVITY_LOCATION));
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Can I register my receivers in this way?

So far, it appears to be working but I'm uncertain if that was just luck or if this will be guaranteed to always work.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this "optimization"? Do you see any performance impact caused by receiver registering?

Comment: I looked on Traceview and saw quite a decrease in loading time if I push it all to a thread. I will double check it now.

Comment: Like mentioned, this might turn out to be a bad idea since, you'd be system with be burdened with spawning a new thread, I guess.

Comment: Not correct.  This would be done in onResume and turned off in onPause.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely fine to do:

```
public void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
synchronized (mReceivers) {
    ReceiverRecord entry = new ReceiverRecord(filter, receiver);
...
```

The `LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver()` is thread safe and the `LocalBroadcastManager` always delivers message on the UI thread (as any broadcast receiver does). The only thing to be careful of is the management of unregistering listeners.

Comment: Synchronizing on `mReceivers` may just be an implementation detail intended to prevent concurrent modification of some of the other collections.  There might be other ways to achieve this, so unless the documentation says that `registerReceiver` is thread safe, I would be wary of depending on this behavior.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, while you have a point about the docs, google isn't perfect and the LocalBroadcastManager code is very old and hasn't changed much over time. If you're really worried, you can bring the code in-house as it's very small and very simple.